# How to custom Class to_string for std::cout

Tags: c++

I find following boost code

```
        for (auto entry : boost::make_iterator_range(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir_path), {})) {
            std::cout << entry << std::endl;
        }
```

entry can be output with dir path, I guess c++ has feature like java Class#toString to custom output string, I try following code:

```
class C {
    str to_string() {
        return "prpr";
    }
};

TEST_F(FileTest, Draft1) {
    C c;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

I expect output "prpr", but it doesn't work, how to fix it?

Comment: C++ is not Java, don't try to make parallels between them. You need to overload `operator <<` for it to work, or call your `to_string` method explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't call any "to_string" or similar function automatically. Instead you must overload the `operator<<` function for your class:

```
class C
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, C const& c)
    {
        return os << "prpr";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a class to `std::cout` you need to overload the `<<` operator for `std::ostream` in your class.

```
class C {
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c){
    os<<"prpr";
    return os;
}
```